# How to test a function with different inputs

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, testing, reactjs

```
function addTwo (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

//Leave the function call
addTwo(50, 100);
```

I'm learning React and I'm trying to create a codecademy type site as a 'learning project', but have run into a JS problem.

Say you have the function above, how do you test it for more than one case? So far I'm testing with:

```
eval(CODE PULLED IN HERE) === 150 ? alert('Correct!') : alert('Wrong!');
```

which is obviously going to alert Correct, which is ok for this case. But for other questions (and even this one) I'm going to want more than one test case and that's where I'm stuck.

So, how can I test for multiple test cases, or is there just a whole other way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Any help/tips greatly appreciated,

For those who know React here's some code to see a bit of what I currently have :

```
const CodeEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    var initialValue = [
      "function addTwo () {",
      "  ",
      "}",
      "//Leave the function call",
      "addTwo(50, 100);"
  ].join("\n");

    return {
      kataValue: initialValue
    }
  },
  onChange (newValue) {
    this.setState({kataValue: newValue});
  },
  evalCode () {
    var val = this.state.kataValue
    eval(val) === 150 ? alert('Correct!') : alert('Wrong!');
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="code-editor-wrapper">
        <AceEditor
          name="editor"
          mode="sh"
          theme="chaos"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.kataValue}
          editorProps={{$blockScrolling: true}}
        />
      <button onClick={this.evalCode} className="spec-btn submit-code-btn">Evaluate</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: can you use `Math.random()` to create the input and result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the function call in the user's code. Only require the function to be named in a certain way. Instead of directly evaling the user's code, embed into a function that returns the user's function:

```
function getUserFunction(code, functionName) {
  var userCode = new Function(code + '; return ' + functionName + ';');
  return userCode();
}
```

After calling `getUserFunction` you have a reference to the function the user wrote and you can execute it as often as you want. How you structure your test cases and how much feedback you want to give to the user is up to you.

Here is small example:

```
var userFn = getUserFunction(this.state.kataValue, 'addTwo');
var testCases = [
  [[50, 100], 150],
  [[1, 2], 3],
];
var passes = testCases.every(
  ([input, output]) => userFn(...input) === output
);
if (passes) {
  // all test cases pass
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm trying to implement this right now. So I've put your second code snippit in my evalCode function. Where do I put your first code snippit (the getUserFunction fn declaration)?

Comment: Wherever you want. You can put it above the component definition or make it a method on the component. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a bunch of inputs like so:

```
function addTwo(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
for (var i = 0, j; i < 100; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    if (addTwo(i, j) !== i + j) console.error('Wrong output for inputs ' + i + ' and ' + j)
  }
}
```